# How does the photon arise from the $U(1)$ symmetry in QED?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I'm trying to study a bit of QED and I really don't get where the photon does arise.

I know that we want our field theory to be gauge invariant under a $U(1)$ phase transformation, because that is what we measure.

But how do we get from the demand for gauge invariance to the photon?

Comment: try a toy model with a complex scalar, then apply local U(1) gauge transformation to the scalar. Unless you introduce gauge-covariant derivative, the theory is not invariant.

Comment: @Kosm Yes that is my problem actually, like I know we need a covariant derivative to make the theory gauge invariant. But how does the photon arise from this? I really don't get the transition from "new gauge invariant derivative" to "a photon arises there"

Comment: @Daniele Derivative of a scalar is a vector, so covariant derivative must equal normal derivative plus some vector that appropriately transforms under U(1) and restores gauge invariance. This vector is photon.